# Se eu declarar uma variável em uma query SELECT ela é obrigatória?

Tags: php, pdo, oracle

Meu problema é que nem sempre vou receber as variáveis, então preciso de uma maneira que não as torne obrigatórias mesmo declarando-as, por exemplo na query abaixo:

`"SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE clientes.nome = :nome";`

A var `:nome` é obrigatória;

então eu preciso que mesmo se a variável `:nome` não contenha um valor, a query me retorna todos os clientes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendo fazer isso direto ao php.

Você pode usar um `if` para fazer isso, como o Stéfano sugeriu, ou de uma forma mais simplificada:

```
$sql = empty($nome) ? "SELECT * FROM clientes" : "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE clientes.nome = :nome";
```

Answer (score 4):

Faça a verificação com **IF**.

```
if(!empty($nome)){
$where = "clientes.nome = :nome";
} else {$where = "";}

$query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE $where";
```

Você pode editar o **else** para adicionar outras regras no **where**.